# Jenkins JFrog Plugin - Distribution not found at provided URL

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I have set up self hosted JFrog instance (JFrog Artifactory OSS) and Jenkins in my local.

I have installed Artifactory Plugin in my Jenkins.

In the configuration for JFrog, I have provided both JFrog Artifactory URL and JFrog Distribution URL.

Artifactory URL provided: **/8082/artifactory**
Distribution URL provided: **/8082/distribution**

When Jenkins tries to test the connection, it says JFrog Artifactory found at provided URL, but distribution not found at provided URL.

Is there any workaround to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JFrog Distribution** is one of services running under JFrog Platform (alongside with Artifactory), which needs to be installed separately and configured to work with your Artifactory.

Please keep in mind that Distribution is only avaliable for the Artifactory **Enterprise+** license.

As an alternative you can try JFrog Cloud to have Distribution service installed: https://jfrog.com/start-free/